# Get filenames from directory from same extension but without the extension (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new at MATLAB, so forgive if I'm saying stuff that is completely wrong. I am trying to write a little program that reads in the files from a certain directory with extension .xlsx and then assigns the columns to vectors. When I manually give up the file names, my program looks like this:

```
files = {'130926','130927'}
file_number = 1;
file_amount = length(files);
while file_number <= file_amount
file_name = files(file_number);
cd('C:\place_where_I_store_my_files');
A = xlsread(char(strcat(file_name)));
J = A(:,1);
J_sp = A(:,2);
file_number = file_number + 1
end
```

I've tried a lot of different things to read in the files automatically among wich:

```
files = {'*.xlsx'}
```

But it all yields errors.
Thanks for reading.

Matthias

Comment: What errors is it giving you? That kind of information makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this did it for me:

```
files = dir('C:\Users\Matthias\Desktop\KUL\2e_Master\Thesis\MBR_data\MBR_online\*cs.xlsx')
file_number = 1;
file_amount = length(files);
while file_number <= file_amount
file_name = files(file_number).name;
cd('C:\place_where_I_store_my_files');
A = xlsread(char(file_name));
J = A(:,1);
J_sp = A(:,2);
file_number = file_number + 1
end
```

Greetings,
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function with a wildcard search.

```
my_path = 'C:\place_where_I_store_my_files';
xlsfiles = dir(fullfile(my_path, '*.xlsx'));
for ii = 1 : length(xlsfiles)
  disp(fullfile(my_path, xlsfiles(ii).name));
end
```

The above code will display the names of all *xlsx* files in the directory you specify.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It does show me the file names that are present in that directory, but I need it to put those in an array that can than be used in the code above. So the file names generated by the code above should be put into $files = {}$. And it should be only the names without the extension .xlsx.

Comment: @Matthias I don't understand what you mean by `$files = {}$`. To get the file names only, call the [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function.

Comment: when I use the `fileparts` function it gives an error saying that the input must be a row vector or characters...

Answer (score 0):

How about this :-

```
>> list = dir('C:\path\*.xlsx');
>> names=cellfun(@(x)x(1:end-5),{list.name},'UniformOutput', false);
```

Access using `names{1}`, `names{2}`... so on

This creates an anonymous function that works on cells of names received from `dir` command.

Type : **`help dir`** and **`help cellfun`** for more details at command prompt

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this on my directory and it worked. But not entirely. Apart from the three file names of the files present in the folder, it also returned [1x0 char] twice. I think that because of this the rest of my code yields an error when I use names as input for it.

Comment: @Matthias yes there must be some other code that's generating those extra `[1x0 char]`, you can verify this simply typing this a your command windows